# Get inner array values in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here result variable is taken from Google analytics API which has two columns. So I want to access to the 1st column value of results by putting results into a 2D array. But the following code is not working.

```
vay sheet1 = [];

        for (i=0;i<results.getRows().length;i++){
        sheet1.push(results.getRows()[i]);
          }

    var s= [];
      s = [sheet1[0][1]];
    return s;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the whole first column then you need to put it in the loop

```
var sheet1 = [];
var s= [];

for (i=0;i<results.getRows().length;i++){
    sheet1.push(results.getRows()[i]);
    s.push(sheet1[i][0]);
}

return s;
```

and another thing 1st column means 0 index.